# Best way of updating a parquet file that depends on it's own data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have a parquet file, where I store a number of metrics by user.
Until now I have recalculated this file in it's entirety, but the calculations are complex, so I want to overwrite just specific columns.

There are two approaches:

- Adding new rows
- Adding columns

So for example when adding new rows, I want to do something like this:

```
df_old = sqlContext.read.parquet(myfile)
df_new = df_other_src.select(...)
df_new = df_old.alias("o").join(df_new.alias("n"), "o.id == n.id", "right")\
  .where("o.id is NULL").select("n.id")
df_new.write.parquet(myfile,mode="append")
```

The trouble is that this does not work because `df_new` depends on `df_old`. What's the best way of solving this?

Answer (score 2):

Few Days back I ran with the issue. So what I did was

1. Read the old parquet file and new data
2. Merge those data and create new Dataframe
3. Write this Dataframe in any temp directory
4. Delete old directory and rename temp directory to old directory

If I did not do this, Every time the job ran it created a lots of file which are empty and small size.

I hope this provides you idea as well.

Comment: Yes, I get that but really hope I don't need to go down that road. I'm aware that if I create another column like `date_added`write the file using `mode="append", partitionBy="date_added '` it should work, but I don't really want to add an artificial column.

Comment: Yeah if you just add a column, just saving on the append mode would be great.

Comment: It does not work for me when just appending either. It only seems to be reliable (tested over 1000 iterations) if I add and partition by a column where the specific partition did not yet exist.